# Finding areas covered by features

Tags: image-processing

I have an image as attached [image]

The blue to yellow to red points are the points of interest the algorithm found, while the pink points are the radius per point. This maps pretty fine, but the issue I am having is that I need to find the area covered by this, but there are usually small holes, or when the direction changes, theres a bigger hole. How can I find the areas covered?

My vector contains x,y position of a point, radius r of how big the vessel is, and the direction o, stating in which direction the vessel orients. But I have no good idea on how to find the area in there.

Comment: You could fill circular regions centered at each point in a separate bitmap, then count the filled pixels in that bitmap.

Comment: Ha, I like that idea. Circles with radius r at every x,y